# Excel countif integer but exclude date value

Tags: excel, countif

I have a basic Excel file to log healthcare survey completed each week, identified by its Project ID, city, type of facility, date completed, and person assigned.

For the week of 10/02/17, I just want to count the number of projects completed that starts in the 17000s; ignore projects in the 1000s.

For example, week of 10/02/17, North zone, =COUNTIF(H3:L9,">17000") = 11. My expected result is 4 not 11 as I want to exclude the date values from the count. See image [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xkb6.png) for clarification. Thanks

```
=COUNTIF(H3:L9,">17000")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply edit your countif statement to exclude the rest of the cells.

`=COUNTIF(H3:H9, ">17000")`

Comment: Is there any way I can get count for an entire week in one formula? Every week, I have a full schedule for 5 zones (north, south, center, west and east) plus an optional zone. For example, from the screenshot, if west zone was scheduled, what argument can I add to countif to make it work, =countif(b3:l9, ">17000")

Comment: Will do. Thanks acousticismX for the quick response.